# Two different results using two different ways to solve limit, how come

Tags: limits

So im learning about limits from tutorials and at the same time im solving the examples myself. Im getting solutions that sometimes differ from the explainer's.

Lets take this limit and the way it is solved on the video:

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \dfrac { (x^3 - x^2 - 6x)}{(x^2+2x)}$$
$$\lim_{x \to -2}\dfrac {x(x^2 - x - 6)}{x(x+2)}$$
$$\lim_{x \to -2} \dfrac {(x+2)(x-3)}{(x+2)}$$
$$\lim_{x \to -2} (x-3)=-5$$

If i try solving it by taking the highest power as per the rule,

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \dfrac {(x^3 - x^2 - 6x)}{(x^2+2x)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \dfrac {x^3}{x^2}$$

$$\lim_{x \to -2} x=-2$$

or is the rule only for limits at infinity? Its a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, only for limit at infinity for rational fraction $P_n(x)/S_m(x)$

Comment: The second method is wrong. You cant simplify the limit that way. The limit is not at infinity.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah i see, thank you for the confirmation. In my textbook this rule has been used even for non-fractions, like a simple polynom. for ex lim x^3+5x = x^3. Or do we take Sm as 1?

Comment: @Aryadeva gotcha thanks!!

Comment: @Bryar Yes, that is a particular case.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah aight thank you again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result is correct. You can get a confirmation by l'Hospital rule since you limit is of the form $0/0$.

Taking the derivatives of numerator and denominator, we find

$$\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{3x^2-2x-6}{2x+2}=\frac{10  }{-2}=-5$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3-x^2-6x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to\infty} 1-\frac 1x-\frac{6}{x^2}=1$$

This limit being $1$ is why you can substitute out the two functions in limits. In general:

$$\lim_{x\to \alpha}g(f(x))= \lim_{x\to\alpha}g(f_\alpha(x))\iff \lim_{x\to\alpha}\frac{f(x)}{f_\alpha(x)}=1$$

What this means in a graphical sense is that both $f$ and $f_\alpha$ converge at the same rate to the same value when $x$ approaches $\alpha$.

In your example, we note that $$\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x^3-x^2-6x}{x^3}=1-(-\frac12)-(\frac32)=0$$
and so this condition is failed. Hence we can't substitute the expressions in our limit.

The first method is exactly the way to do it, because given $P(x)=Q(x)\frac{x-\beta}{x-\beta}$, we have that $$\lim_{x\to\beta} P(x)=\lim_{x\to\beta} Q(x)$$